# Singularity Detection from 2D Wavelet Modulus Plot

Tags: matlab, wavelet, python, edge-detection, 2d

I was wondering if I could get some tips/resources on how to pick out the singularity from my 2D Continuous Wavelet Transform Coefficient Plot (scalogram) using the Gaussian Derivative as the mother-wavelet (the Mexican-Hat works well as well).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5gRe.png) is an example of a plot.

How do I prevent false detections? What is the best way to sort through this to find the singularity? Should I only be looking at one scale and do a 1D signal peak Detection?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!